# Why doesn't angular bundle .esm files for packages with module options?

Tags: javascript, angular, bundling-and-minification, commonjs

I'm trying to fix some issues with cjs modules in my angular application, that is giving me warnings. To focus on one example, [jsondiffpatch](https://github.com/benjamine/jsondiffpatch), i have installed the latest version (0.4.1). When running a `ng build`, I get the following from angular cli:

```
Warning: [filepath/some-component.ts] depends on 'jsondiffpatch'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
```

However, when clicking into the installed `jsondiffpatch` package, I can see that the `package.json` does indeed link to an esm build `"module": "dist/jsondiffpatch.esm.js"`.

It seems I am misunderstanding how bundling works. Why would angular not recognise/use the esm file and instead opt to use the cjs file (if that is what is happening)? And how can i correct this?